# Fetch results added today no earlier

Tags: mysql, sql

I am having trouble wrapping my head around a query I'm supposed to write.

I've got two tables: stock and articles

Columns in articles:

- id
- name
- price

Columns in stock:

- id
- articleId
- tstamp_in (yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss)

For every article that is delivered to me by my suppliers, I create a new row in the stock table. That means that every article can have multiple rows in the stock table. One of my colleges asked if I could supply a list that shows him all new articles, so in other words all records from stock that have a tstamp_in value higher than last midnight.

I came to the following query but I really cant figure out how to get the result I am looking for.

```
SELECT *
FROM stock
LEFT JOIN articles ON stock.articleId=articles.id
WHERE tstamp_in>'2015-01-12 00:00:00'
```

This gives me all records in the stock table created after last midnight. However this does not mean that there aren't any previous records. What I'm trying to figure out is how I can get this in one query.

In short:

**Select all from stock grouped by articleId where tstamp_in > 2015-01-12 00:00:00 and not having records with that articleId before 2015-01-12 00:00:00**

Is this possible?

Comment: Why not use WHERE DATE(tstamp_in) = YOURCURRENTDATE ? (i.e. = DATE(NOW())

Comment: @LokiSinclair I need the results to be newer then 12 o'clock last night.

Comment: @LokiSinclair, wrapping the `tstamp_in` in the `DATE()` function would render any index unusable.. better would be `tstamp_in >= CURDATE()`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Think of the the problem a bit differently.  For what articles is the *earliest* `tstamp_in` today?  That leads you to an aggregation and `having`:

```
select s.articleId
from stock s
group by s.articleId
having min(tstamp_in) > '2015-01-12'
```

Comment: I'd probably change that to `>= CURDATE()`